# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la información que ponga en un .TXT no se sobrescriba al ingresar la información por c++ y al ejecutarlo por segunda vez?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

El siguiente codigo se encarga de guardar información en un bloc de notas, mi problema es que al guardar información por primera vez en en el bloc de notas, todo sale bien, pero cuando ejecuto por segunda vez el programa y guardo información en el mismo bloc de notas, la información que había puesto anteriormente se sobre pierde ya que la nueva se sobrescribe y esa no es la idea. La verdad no tengo la menor idea de como solucionarlo así que agradeceria mucho que pudieran ayudarme  porque ando empezando con este tema y me siento re perdido.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

void crearPP();
void LPP();
void anotarPP();
void menu();

int main(){
    menu();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
} 

void menu()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");
    int elec;
    cout<<"¿Qué desea agregar?:"<<endl<<endl;
    do
    {
        cout<<"1.- Crear agenda"<<endl;
        cout<<"2.- Agregar contacto a la agenda"<<endl;
        cout<<"3.- Mostrar contactos de agenda"<<endl;
        cout<<"4.- Salir"<<endl;
        cout<<"Elija una opción: \t";
        cin>>elec;
        switch(elec)
        {
            case 1:
                system("cls");
                crearPP();
                break;
            case 2:
                system("cls");
                anotarPP();
                break;
            case 3:
                system("cls");
                LPP();
                break;
            case 4:
                system("cls");
                cout<<"Hasta luego"<<endl;
                break;
            default:
                system("cls");
                cout<<"Seleccionaste una opción inexistente"<<endl<<endl;
                cout<<"Intenta nuevamente"<<endl;
                break;
        }
    } 
    while(elec!=4);
}

void crearPP(){
    ofstream archivo;
    string nombreArchivo,frase;
    char rpt;
    
    cout<<"Ingrese el nombre de la agenda: ";
    fflush(stdin);
    getline(cin,nombreArchivo);
    
    archivo.open(nombreArchivo.c_str(),ios::out); //Creamos el archivo
    
    if(archivo.fail()){ //Si a ocurrido algun error
        cout<<"No se pudo abrir el archivo";
        exit(1);
    }

    archivo.close(); //Cerramos el archivo
}

void LPP()
{
    string nombre;
    string linea;
 
    cout << "Dime el nombre de la agenda: "; 
    fflush(stdin);   
    getline(cin, nombre);
 
    ifstream fichero(nombre.c_str());
    if( fichero.fail() )
    {
        cout << "No existe el fichero!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
 
    while (! fichero.eof()) 
    {
        getline(fichero,linea);
        if (! fichero.eof()) 
            cout << linea << endl;
    }
    fichero.close();
 
}

 void anotarPP(){
    ofstream archivo;
    string a,b;
    char c;
    cout<<"Ingresa el nombre de la agenda: ";
    fflush(stdin);   
    getline(cin,a);
    archivo.open(a.c_str(),ios::out); 
    if(archivo.fail())
    { 
    cout<<"No se puede abrir el documento";
    exit(1);
    }
    do{
    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"Dijite el contacto a guardar: ";
    getline(cin,b);
    archivo<<b<<endl;
    cout<<"Desea escribir mas?: "; 
    cin>>c;
    }while((c=='S')||(c=='s'));
    archivo.close(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Principalmente, tu problema reside en la siguiente linea :

```
archivo.open(a.c_str(),ios::out);
```

Aquí, debes cambiar `ios::out` por `ios_base::app` de esta forma, indicas que vas a añadir text al archivo y no ha sobreescribirlo.

Es decir, tu linea de código debería de verse ahora de esta forma :

```
archivo.open(a.c_str(),ios_base::app);
```

Te adjunto ahora [este enlace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/) donde tienes toda la información sobre los modos que tienes para tratar archivos donde se informa de que `ios_base::app` hace referencia a `append` y donde se mencionan todos los otros diferentes modos.

Comment: Ya lo solucione gracias a ti, muchas gracias de verdad, ya andaba desesperado xd